# Rails: How to convert <img src= > to image_tag in rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first post here and it might sound awfully stupid. Im building my first rails app.

I have this line in my `index.html.erb`

```
    <img src="/assets/rand_front/<%= @random_image%>", style='height:50vw;width:100vw;margin-bottom:20px;' >
```

I want to use `image_tag`instead  of the `img src`

What is the correct way to wrap it around the code?

So far I've tried `<%= image_tag ( "/assets/rand_front/<%= @random_image%>", style='height:50vw;width:100vw;margin-bottom:20px;') %>`

and 
`<%= image_tag ( "/assets/rand_front/<%= @random_image%>"), style='height:50vw;width:100vw;margin-bottom:20px;' %>`

and many other versions, but none seems to work, what am I doing wrong? and how should I write it properly?

this `<%= @random_image%>` bit is taking this variable from the `index` method in the controller.

```
def index
   @products = Product.all.order(created_at: :desc).group_by(&:category_id)
    @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg"]
    @random_no = rand(10)
    @random_image = @images[@random_no]
end
```

Comment: BTW, you can use `@random_image = "#{rand(1..10)}.jpg"` or – if these are just placeholders – `@random_image = @images.sample`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<%= image_tag "rand_front/#{@random_image}", style: 'height:50vw;width:100vw;margin-bottom:20px;' %>
```

`image_tag` will automatically add `assets` at start of the path

check [Image Tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)  for Documentation

Answer (score 2):

This is what Ruby on Rails is explicitly processing

```
 <%= image_tag("source", {:style => "width:100px;"}) %>
```

(meaning that Ruby allows you to use this code with out the ( { } ),

For me, first starting out its important to know that this is how Ruby on Rails actually running the code.

In other words YES you could leave the ( { } ) formality out because Ruby will understand your code, hope that helps to clarify some...

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you have a `rand_front` folder in your assets folder so you should call `image_tag("#{@random_image}")` since by default the `image_tag` helper should check all the folders in the assets directory for the image name

For the CSS properties you can consider using the `options` hash which would allow you to pass in the CSS properties as keys with your desired values

`image_tag("#{@random_image}", height: 20, width: 20)` You can check out the documentation in the previous answer